# Change variable value within async function - node.js

Tags: node.js

```
var url = posts.paging.next;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function(url,i) {
request(url,{json:true}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  url = body.paging.next;
  console.log(i+"+++"+url)
  }
});
    })(url,i);
};//for
```

According to async request response (body.paging.next),  İ want to change value of **var url**  which is top of code .Please Help

NOTE: i'm trying to get all comments from facebook api , To do that , i need to get page links . Because of this , i wrote this codes , if you have any other alternative way please suggest them thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're trying to perform the requests in sequence (e.g. the next request relies on the url from the previous request), you could do something like (using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module):

```
var async = require('async');

// ...

var url = posts.paging.next, i = 0;

async.whilst(
  function() { return i < 3; },
  function(callback) {
    ++i;
    request(url, { json: true }, function(err, response, body) {
      // TODO: handle `err`
      //return callback(err);

      if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
        url = body.paging.next;
        console.log(i + '+++' + url);
        callback();
      }
    });
  },
  function(err) {
    // done!
  }
);
```

Comment: this is correct answer , thank you so much , i was using async module differently some times , at this time you and async saved my time and i got some node.js experiance point :D